# Algorithm for the direction in which user moves

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I want to show custom car / bike image in the direction of which user moving, right now the problem is that, bike goes in the direction of which user moves, but when user come reverse it bike also shown in reverse mode.

Below is the code :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bike.png"];
    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);
    return annotationView;

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;


    currentLocation = newLocation;
    previousLocation = oldLocation;
    if(currentLocation != nil)
    {
        if (myAnnotation)
        {
            [self.myMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for the `course` attribute of `CLLocation` class, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/course

Comment: @Raul : course value all the time -1, can you help regarding that ?

Comment: As stated in the docs `A negative value indicates that the direction is invalid` this may happen since `course` values may not be available in all devices (maybe the device doesn't have the proper hardware?)